# Beginner's piano for adults

Tags: piano, beginner

I am teaching using John Thompson's piano course for adults for the first time and would like to know what standard, in terms of grades, pupils are at by the end of the book.

Answer (score 2):

there's 2 books I think

if it's this one: John Thompson's Modern Course for the Piano

then it can be up to [grade 3](https://us.abrsm.org/fileadmin/user_upload/syllabuses/pianoSyllabusComplete17.pdf) because you go up to Ab major as well as know some more advanced hand positions

if it's this one: John Thompson's Adult Piano Course

it's probably mid level 2 because you don't get the hand positions

Comment: I'm just starting piano, what are grades in this context?

Comment: it's based on ABRSM syllabus: https://ie.abrsm.org/fileadmin/user_upload/syllabuses/pianoSyllabusComplete15.pdf